# SSAS OLAP Cube - Sum measure only works when keys are present

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, measure

*(This is a mock of my actual setup to help me figure out the problem.)*

---

I have one fact table and one dimension table, linked by an id field.

[image]

#### My goal is to make a measure that sums up all "thing_count" (integer) values in my cube.

If the user splits by nothing, it should show the total "thing_count" for all records in the fact table. If it's split by "category_name" from the dimension, it should show the total "thing_count" for each category.

I tried to achieve this by creating a SUM measure in my cube:

[image]

#### It works, but not in the way I intend it to

It always shows (null) *unless* I drag in the "id" field from the dimension.

#### Measure only:

[image]

---

#### Measure and category:

[image]

---

#### Measure, category, and id:

[image]

---

## How can I make the measure show the value without keys needing to be present?

---

**Edit:**

For GregGalloway's request (I've edited the names so the screenshots are easier to follow):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you go to the DSV and explore the dimension table to view the rows in it? I want to see a screenshot of the row or rows where id=1 in your dimension. And can you screenshot the Dimension Usage tab in the cube editor? And can you screenshot the Attribute Relationships tab of the dimension editor?

Comment: You can skip the above request if my answer fixes the problem, obviously.

Comment: Screenshots added @GregGalloway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common explanation for this behavior (no aggregation) is that you have inadvertently commented out the `CALCULATE;` statement in your MDX script in the cube. Please check that statement is still present.

Comment: I'm not using my own MDX script to generate the measure. I'm using the built-in method through SSAS per the screenshots in my question.

Comment: Can you go to the Calculations tab of the cube designer and switch to the Script View and screenshot it? I want to be 100% sure the CALCULATE statement is still there.

Comment: See screenshot in original post. There aren't any calculated members. Form view shows "There are currently no calculations defined for this model."

Comment: So you need to add the following to the MDX script and deploy. That should fix it: `CALCULATE;`

Comment: I **CAN'T** believe that's what was causing this issue. I saw that exact answer on other posts, but in context of people creating their own MDX measures. I didn't know you needed that statement there even if you're just using the in-built measure generator. Your bounty will be delivered to you tomorrow Greg!

Comment: @Lil'Bits i think this is the shortest bounty ever. :) In order to get more upvotes for the question and answer, don't offer the bounty until its time ends

Comment: It was a very well asked question. You have my upvote. Glad we could find a quick solution. Cheers